# Should I pass context.Context to underlying DB methods in Go?

Tags: mongodb, go, go-context

I use semi-code here just to show my intention of whats going on in code and not complicating things here in the question.

I have a `main.go` file that calls a method that connects to mongoDB database:

```
mStore := store.NewMongoStore()
```

In `NewMongoStore` I have context that `client.Connect` uses to connect to database:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
```

Now in `main.go` I pass the store to my router controller file this way:

```
routes.GenericRoute(router, mStore)
```

In `GenericRoute` I get the mStore and pass it to function handlers:

```
func GenericRoute(router *gin.Engine, mStore store.Store) {
    router.POST("/users", controllers.CreateUser(mStore))
}
```

Now in `CreateUser` I again create a context as below to insert document into MongoDB:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
defer cancel()

insertedId, err := repo.CreateUser(ctx, newUser{"John", "Doe"})
```

Here I passed context to `createUser` to insert a new document.

As you see in some parts I have passed context and in some parts I did not. I really do not have any idea what I should do? What is the correct way to work with contexts? Should I always pass context around or it is totally ok to create new contexts like this to not pass context in method parameters.

**What is the best practice for** this kind of coding? And which one is better from performance point of view?

Comment: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/context-cancellation-and-values/ here is good overview why and how to use contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached to an interesting answer to my own question, so I prefer to put here for future users if having the same question in mind.

If I pass the SAME context that I have connected to Mongo with to `userController` and pass it down further to `CreateUser` function:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
```

**NOTE:** instead of cancelling context in `NewMongoStore` function I `defer cancel()` it in `main` function.

After 10 seconds if you call `POST /users` you will get `context deadline exceeded`, so basically you cannot use this context to do other stuff and you have to create new context on each `CreateUser` call.

So what I have written is fine. I wait for 10 seconds to connect to `mongo` in my example and 1 second for my insert operation context.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my experience, `Context` has two major use cases:

1. Pass down information. For your question, you might want to generate a `request_id` for each request and passing it down to the lowest part of your code, and logging this `request_id` to do error tracing across the whole code base.

   1. This feature is not always useful, for example you want to initialise a MongoDB connection, but it's done during service start-up. At this time there's no meaningful context, a `context.Background` with timeouts should be good enough.
   2. Be cautious with mutating values retrieved from `Context`, this could cause concurrent access if you're passing the `Context` all around.
2. Auto-cancellation and timeouts. These two features doesn't come from nothing, you need to tune your code to handle these informations from the `Context`. But most third-party and standard libraries with an `Context` parameter can handle these two features gracefully (e.g. database libraries, HTTP call libraries). With this feature you can auto reclaim resources once the `Context` invalidated.

   1. Sometime you'll want to stop this cascading behaviour, for example writing logs in the background goroutine, then you need to create a new `context.Background()` to avoid these writes get cancelled once upstream context cancelled. `context.Background()` also clears the information context so sometime you need to extract the context information from the upstream context, and manually append them to this new context.

It's a bit overkill to force a `Context` parameter to all functions, (there's no point to add `Context` to a simple `greatestCommonDivisor` function) but adding a `Context` parameter to anywhere you need it never hurts. `Context` has good enough performance, for your use case (HTTP server & database writing), it should not cause visible overhead to your service.

Comment: So don't you think creating context on each http call to `POST /users` is decreasing performance? Or is bad practice?

Comment: It's not a bad practice, gRPC generates API calls with `Context` parameter by default. Actually it's bad to worry about function-call performance when coding a backend server, it's very unlikely that you'll hit the bottleneck issues in your code, it's more likely that your cache service or database or even gateway server hit it. Design the system `with` performance in your head, instead `for` it.